# MySQL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT and combine

Tags: mysql, random, limit

I have 2 tables (tmp1,tmp2). Every table contains unique (product)_id's only. I need to create a query to get a fixed and random number of ID's from table tmp2 for each ID from table tmp1. I've tried it with GROUP_CONCAT, but get's error:

```
SELECT p.products_id,
GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT tmp2.products_id FROM tmp2 tmp2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12))
FROM tmp1 tmp1
GROUP BY tmp1.products_id
LIMIT 1
```

"subquery returned more than one record"

That's the result I need.

example:

---

```
ID tmp1 | ID tmp2    
      1 | 103,204,867,547,354,514,541    
      2 | 542,245,876,542,681,248,428
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Is there any relation defined between these 2 tables ?

Comment: Where is your join clause?

Comment: I think he wants to pick n random values from tmp2 for each row in tmp1

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` should be in the subquery. This way the subquery will return only one record.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel That's right. I added a delimiter in the subquery and get no more errors, but LIMIT doesn't work. I get all ID's from tmp2 for each ID from tmp1?!

Comment: I've got this:

SELECT *
FROM tmp1
  CROSS JOIN
        (
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID)
   FROM  tmp2
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 5
  ) a

but the subquery returns the same random IDs  for each joined row so not quite there yet....
I'm wondering if creating a function to do the subquery bit is the way to go....

Comment: the same happens with me also with other query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got there in the end with the help of a function

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION randomness() RETURNS VARCHAR(10000)
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE randomnum VARCHAR(500);

    SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(ID)
    INTO    randomnum
    FROM    (
                SELECT  ID
                FROM    tmp2
                ORDER   BY RAND()
                LIMIT   12
            ) a;
    RETURN  randomnum;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT   *,
        (SELECT randomness())
FROM    tmp1
```

As per your last comment below, the results can be added to a new table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp3
(
    ID INT,
    RandomNums VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO tmp3
SELECT *,
        (SELECT randomness())
FROM    tmp1
```

Comment: WOW! It works! Where is the box I can put money in it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Haha. No money required, hitting the tick button will do ;)

Comment: Sorry, where is the tick button?

Comment: under the down arrow on the left of my answer "click to accept this answer" when you hover over it

Comment: appreciated :))

Comment: Last question. The function works if the result is written in a temporary table, but if I want to write the result in a new table with CREATE TABLE tmp3 before SELECT the process is running endless

Comment: Less success. I created tmp3 manually and run the query again but with LIMIT 1000. It takes 31 seconds. For all data it will take around 1 hour.... strange...

Comment: Probably best to raise another question on that one and include the relevant info as it's a bit beyond the scope of this question